# Cuurently processed filename as first column of the target table(informatica mapping)

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In my mapping ,I have added currently processed file name as first column and 1st column of my source is id and 2nd is name.

while executing the workflow it is showing error as id cannot be assigned the value in name column. It seems id is assigned to filename and for id column its fetching the name.

Help pls.

Comment: Could you please post the session log and screenshot of the applicable part of your mapping

Comment: Try setting the "currently processed file name" as the very last port.

Comment: Yes it helped,I added it as  last port  instead of making it as first and then I mapped it to first position in the target.Thanks